# SQL Server table gets re-created, losing historical data

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that keeps getting re-created, due to which history data gets lost.

I am unable to track what is causing this table to re-create.

I have created a trigger, and also went through SQL Server event logs but found nothing that indicates the cause for the re-creation of this table.

Please suggest a solution how to identify the cause of the table re-creation and steps to prevent it from happening.

Comment: If the table is *actually* dropped and created fresh, simply remove the permission to do such actions to the user(s) that use your application. If the table is instead cleared of data, you should be able to use `INSTEAD OF DELETE` triggers to log, or use the logs/profiler to find it. Are you sure the program(s) in question are actually committing their transactions correctly?

Comment: More information needed. Are you use EntityFramework or some other framework in you application using database? You can use SqlServer Profiler to see "who does what"

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependencies of your table and see if there is any unwanted proc or trigger that is causing that